# open Window which holds a ViewModel as argument

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window, viewmodel

I need to use a FlowDocumentScrollViewer to display reports. Since FlowDocument is not the easiest control to work with I need to access two observablecollections from another ViewModel in the code behind from the View.

When I click in the menu to open up the window I send a message which opens up the window

```
case "ShotListReportView":
      var ShotListReportWindow = new ShotListReportView();
      ShotListReportWindow.Show();
      break;
```

The new ShotListReportView() gives an error: doesn't take 0 arguments.

That's because in the constructor of of the window I have a ViewModel as argument, which I need to generate the report.

```
public ShotListReportView(ShotListViewModel ShotListViewModel)
{
    ShotList = ShotListViewModel.AllShots;
    SceneList = ShotListViewModel.SceneCollectionView;

    InitializeComponent();
}
public ListCollectionView SceneList { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Shot> ShotList { get; set; }
```

The reason why I don't use a ViewModel for this window is that I need to work with a FlowDocument and style it in code behind.

How can I open the window with the argument or how can I get access to the ViewModel which holds the observablecollections I need?

Comment: If you just want to open the window,just add an empty constructor of ShotListReportView

Comment: You've designed a number of types. The design doesn't meet your requirements, and you're asking people about how to get workaround for you design. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Joseph and empty constructor will indeed open the window but it will not give me access to the collections, for that I need to call another method which holds an argument to call the ViewModel I need. And I don't know how to formulate that argument in the method. That is the issue right now.

Comment: do you have a main viewmodel concept in your application.

Comment: @Joseph No I don't I have window with several usercontrols which each have their own ViewModel.

Comment: better you keep a mainViewmodel where you will have to add a Property of the required viewmodel that you need to access..